# How can I use images for columns in SSRS graph reports?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to tell SSRS to render a column in a graph as a big arrow, for example to highlight improvements? If the value is >0 it would be an upwards arrow, if it is <0 it would be a downwards arrow, rather than a column.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. You could use a column label to convey the same info though.